# CMake output path for compile pdb files

Tags: cmake, pdb-files

I'm trying to specify the output path for program database (pdb) files of static libraries in CMake. I think CMake calls them compile pdbs, as opposed to linker pdbs.

From CMake's documentation I found out that I can specify the pdb output directory by `COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`. That works as expected. I can also specify the name of the pdb file by `COMPILE_PDB_NAME`. That also works as expected. However, I am getting an extraneous configuration string appended between the directory and the name, which does not seem to be controlled by either of the previous two. That is, the final output path is of the form `C:\mypdboutputpath\RelWithDebInfo\mypdbname.pdb`, where `RelWithDebInfo` corresponds to the current configuration. However, my outputpath already contains my own configuration specifier (my library output directory is of the form `lib\msvc64-relwithdebinfo`). I've been trying to set both global and target-specific pdb-names and directories, but they do not affect whether the configuration-string is appended or not.

How to get rid of the appended configuration string in the pdb output path?

Although Visual Studio is multi-configuration, my approach is to use CMake as if it were single-configuration, i.e. the configuration is chosen when running CMake.

Answer (score 2):

What helped me was setting the property `COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CFG}` instead of `COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`. For your example, it would probably be `COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELWITHDEBINFO`.

I didn't find anything about that in the CMake docs, but since the same thing works for the `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property.
The [CMake docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_CONFIG.html) specifically mention this behavior for this property, so I thought it was worth it to try it with `COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` as well, and it did work. Hopefully it's not some undefined behavior that will change in the future. FWIW I tested it with CMake 3.18.1

Probably too late for the OP, but perhaps it may help some other poor soul like me.